# How to connect spark with cassandra using spark-cassandra-connector?

Tags: python, apache-spark, jar, cassandra, datastax

You must forgive my noobness but I'm trying to setup a spark cluster that connects to cassandra running a python script, currently I am using datastax enterprise to run cassandra on solr search mode. I understand that, in order to use the spark-cassandra connector that datastax provides, you must run cassandra in analytics mode (using -k option). Currently I have got it to work only using the dse spark version, for which, to make it work I followed the next steps:

1. Start dse cassandra in analytics mode
2. change $PYTHONPATH env variable to /path/to/spark/dse/python:/path/to/spark/dse/python/lib/py4j-*.zip:$PYTHONPATH
3. run as root the standalone script with `python test-script.py`

Besides, I made another test using the spark alone (not dse version), trying to include the java packages that make driver classes accesible, I did:

1. Add spark.driver.extraClassPath = /path/to/spark-cassandra-connector-SNAPSHOT.jar to the file spark-defaults.conf
   2.execute `$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit  —packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra...`

I also tried running pyspark shell and test if sc had the method cassandraTable to see if the driver was loaded but didn't work out, in both cases I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'cassandraTable'
```

My goal is to undestand what I must do to make the non-dse spark version connect with cassandra and have the methods from the driver available.

I also want to know if it is possible to use the dse spark-cassandra connector with a cassandra node that is NOT running with dse.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to connect spark-shell to cassandra in non-dse version.

Copy `spark-cassandra-connector` jar to `spark/spark-hadoop-directory/jars/`

```
spark-shell --jars ~/spark/spark-hadoop-directory/jars/spark-cassandra-connector-*.jar
```

in spark shell execute these commands

```
sc.stop
import com.datastax.spark.connector._, org.apache.spark.SparkContext, org.apache.spark.SparkContext._, org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import  org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val csc = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)
```

You will have to provide more parameters if your cassandra has password setup etc. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have used pyspark in a standalone python script. I don't use DSE, I cloned cassandra-spark-connector from datastax's github repository and compiled with datastax [instrucctions](https://github.com/jasset75/Spark-Cassandra-Notes/blob/master/docs/Environment.md#datastax-spark-cassandra-connector).

In order to get access to spark connector within spark, I copied to jars folder inside spark installation.

I think that it would be good for you as well:

```
 cp ~/spark-cassandra-connector/spark-cassandra-connector/target/full/scala-2.11/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-2.0.5-86-ge36c048.jar $SPARK_HOME/jars/
```

You could visit [this](https://jasset75.github.io/Spark-Cassandra-Notes/Environment.html) where I explain my own experience setting up the environment.

Once spark has access to Cassandra connector, you can use pyspark library as wrapper:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .appName('SparkCassandraApp') \
  .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', 'localhost') \
  .config('spark.cassandra.connection.port', '9042') \
  .config('spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level','ONE') \
  .master('local[2]') \
  .getOrCreate()

ds = sqlContext \
  .read \
  .format('org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra') \
  .options(table='tablename', keyspace='keyspace_name') \
  .load()

ds.show(10)
```

In this [example](https://jasset75.github.io/Spark-Cassandra-Notes/Examples/dataset-join-03.html) you can see the whole script.