# Spark with Cassandra python setup

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to use spark to do some simple computations on Cassandra tables, but I am quite lost.

I am trying to follow: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md

So I'm running the PySpark shell: with

```
./bin/pyspark \
  --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.0.0-M3
```

But I am not sure how to set things up from here. How do I let Spark know where my Cassandra cluster is? I've seen that `CassandraSQLContext` can be used for this, but I also read that this is deprecated.

I have read this: [How to connect spark with cassandra using spark-cassandra-connector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082562/how-to-connect-spark-with-cassandra-using-spark-cassandra-connector)

But if I use

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
```

Python says that it can't find the module. 
Can someone maybe point me in the right direction on how to set things up properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandra connector doesn't provide any Python modules. All functionality is provided with [Data Source API](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/01/09/spark-sql-data-sources-api-unified-data-access-for-the-spark-platform.html) and as long as required jars are present, everything should work out of the box.

> How do I let Spark know where my Cassandra cluster is?

Use `spark.cassandra.connection.host` property. You can for exampel pass it as an argument for `spark-submit` / `pyspark`:

```
pyspark ... --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=x.y.z.v
```

or set in your configuration:

```
(SparkSession.builder
    .config("cassandra.connection.host", "x.y.z.v"))
```

Configuration like table name or keyspace can be set directly on reader:

```
(spark.read
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .options(table="kv", keyspace="test", cluster="cluster")
    .load())
```

So you can follows [Dataframes](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md) documentation.

As a side note

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
```

is a Scala syntax and is accepted in Python only accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy pyspark-cassandra connector spark-folder/jars.
2. Below code will connect to cassandra.

   ```
   from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
   from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession

   spark = SparkSession.builder \
     .appName('SparkCassandraApp') \
     .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', 'localhost') \
     .config('spark.cassandra.connection.port', '9042') \
     .config('spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level','ONE') \
     .master('local[2]') \
     .getOrCreate()

   sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)
   ds = sqlContext \
     .read \
     .format('org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra') \
     .options(table='emp', keyspace='demo') \
     .load()

   ds.show(10)
   ```

Comment: Where re you giving User name and Password

Answer (score 0):

With username and password:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .appName('SparkCassandraApp') \
  .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', 'localhost') \
  .config('spark.cassandra.connection.port', '9042') \
  .config("spark.cassandra.auth.username","cassandrauser")\
  .config("spark.cassandra.auth.password","cassandrapwd")\
  .master('local[2]') \
  .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
   .options(table="tablename", keyspace="keyspacename").load()

df.show()
```