# Where to add spark commands in python code

Tags: pyspark, cassandra

I am very new to this spark python world so I have another question. It's good to know I can write spark commands in spark shell or python code, so:

```
pyspark --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.5.1\ 
        --files path_to/secure-connect-test.zip \
        --conf spark.cassandra.connection.config.cloud.path=secure-connect-test.zip \
        --conf spark.cassandra.auth.username=UserName \
        --conf spark.cassandra.auth.password=Password \
        --conf spark.dse.continuousPagingEnabled=false
```

This part of code, if I want to write it inside python code, do I have to add it with os.environ command? I have seen some posts with that command but they add a variable. Thanks

Comment: You could set it while creating spark object.  
check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57908610/6275871

Comment: Thank you a lot!